# How do I add Grails to my cloudbees Jenkins installation?

Tags: grails, jenkins, cloudbees

I'm trying to follow the instructions here to run my Grails build on the Cloudbees' Jenkins service:

http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Build+and+Deploy+Grails+application

However, when I try to select a Grails installation for my build job from the "Grails Installation", the drop-down list is empty except for the "Default" option:

[image]

When I run my build I get the following error message as though there are no Grials instances installed:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grails" (in directory "/scratch/jenkins/workspace/liza"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:709)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:934)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:901)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 15 more
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to install Grails myself somehow?

I've tried checking the "Use Grails wrapper" checkbox but I still get a similar issue:

```
[liza] $ /scratch/jenkins/workspace/liza/grailsw upgrade --non-interactive
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/scratch/jenkins/workspace/liza/grailsw" (in directory "/scratch/jenkins/workspace/liza"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `/configure` on your Jenkins server you should see a list of Grails installations. If it is empty, you can add one; select *Use Pre-Installed Grails on DEV@Cloud* and pick one of the offered versions if they suit your needs; or you can select *Install automatically* and get a recent build downloaded from a public mirror.

If these things do not work out, you can always open a support ticket; reference this SO question in case there is a resolution that can help others.

Answer (score 4):

"Use Grails wrapper" will help you here (assuming you're using Grails 2.1 or later).  In your app run

```
grails wrapper
```

[This will create a `grailsw` shell script](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#wrapper) and a few other bits and pieces in your app which you need to check in.  This wrapper script can be used in place of an installed `grails` and it will download its own copy of Grails the first time it is run.  If you tell Jenkins to "use grails wrapper" then it will not require a separate installation of Grails on the build server.

Comment: I already tried that but I still get the same kind of error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/scratch/jenkins/workspace/liza/grailsw"

Comment: @RicardoGladwell Did you definitely check in the `grailsw` script and the `wrapper` directory that `grails wrapper` generated?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry, missed your link.